# Play or cast content from standard player into VrVideoView

Tags: android, google-cardboard, exoplayer, daydream, vrvideoview

I got an android app that plays live/vod content using `QuickPlay`.

This QuickPlay player / controller configured to use `ExoPlayer`.

I didn't wrote this application, but asked to add ***Play in VR*** functionality.

It could be `Cardboard`, `DayDream` or `GearVR` doesn't matter.

I found [SimplyVrVideoActivity](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started) sample by Google,

In this sample the `VrWidgetView` can get 2 types of input:

- mVrVideoView.loadVideoFromAsset(LoaclAsset.mp4, options)
- mVrVideoView.loadVideo(Uri, options)

What if I just want to "cast" already playing content to this `VrVideoView`, any ideas?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: Hi David, have you used Exoplayer that comes with Google VR Sdk or platform version?